# Need a word(s) for a resume that explains a persons' technical mind

Tags: phrase-requests

My husband can fix anything.  Seriously anything.  He has his own business repairing boats and boat engines.  He is applying for a job as a Plant Manager at a boat manufacturer.  I need a phrase that describes his ability to fix anything; his brain is very technical and understands how most anything is put together and can be repaired or made better.  He should have been an engineer.

Comment: Would 2 words do? technically gifted. Or technologically talented.

Comment: "He can fix anything."

Answer (score 1):

A Plant Manager is responsible for directing the work of others.  A person with strong technical skills can be a very effective manager, so long as they can step back and allow a less-experienced person to do the job.

It's important for a manager to identify and hire talent, to organize the work, to set clear expectations for team members, and generally do a whole host of things that are not specifically technical.  An employee's respect for a manager's technical ability can count for a great deal, since it makes the manager's orders easier to accept and carry out.  But management is fundamentally the art of getting work done by others, not doing it yourself.

So I would suggest something like the following, depending on the space you have, and the general tone of the resume:

- Hands-on experience with a wide-range of marine construction and engine work, primarily through making repairs and *explaining the tasks to others.*

The main issue in the hiring manager's mind will be whether the candidate can get the work done.  It's an incredibly difficult step from technical expert to technical manager, and the hiring manager will most likely know this.